# View / sort Podcasts list by subscribed status

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I have roughly 50 different podcasts that, at one time or another, I have subscribed to.  Only about half of those are currently subscribed to.  When I look at my list of episodes in iTunes, the whole list always appears in alphabetical order. I do *not* want to delete my old unsubscribed podcasts from my library, but it would be really nice if there were some way to either hide (and later show) the unsubscribed podcasts, or sort the list so that subscribed podcasts appear at the top. Are either of these possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an automatic sort option to send currently subscribed podcasts to the top of the list. I have the same complaint (among others) with the podcast capabilities of iTunes. There are a couple of ways you can do this manually though.

1. Create a station and only include the podcasts you are currently subscribed to in it.
2. In the "My Podcasts" view, click the "Podcasts" drop-down menu (top right) and sort by "Playlist Order". You can then drag & drop to reorder your podcasts in the left hand pane.

#2 is what I do. You can quickly see whether or not you've subscribed to a podcast when you select it - if you're subscribed it will say "Updated xxxxx" under the podcast title. If you aren't, it will say "Not subscribed" along with the last updated date.

A bit annoying, but it seems that this is the only option. There may be a way to generate a playlist using some scripting, but from looking at the iTunes library file I don't see any information in there that indicates whether or not a podcast is subscribed to. (Someone more familiar with scripting for iTunes may have a better idea here).